# What’s the purpose of an exclamation mark at the start of a block comment? (That is, "/*! … */")

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax, comments

I just found this comment declaration in some xcode sample project:

```
/*!
@property masterVolume
@abstract Sets the master volume
*/
@property float masterVolume;
```

The comment is green as usual, the @property and @ abstract are dark green. If I remove the exclamation mark, they have the same green. What’s the purpose of the exclamation marks?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605535/what-are-documentation-comments-in-xcode ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make transition from headerdoc a bit simpler, appledoc (tool to generate documentation from code so you save time in documentation) also accepts headerdoc style multiline comments:

```
/*! Comment */
```

[Source](http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp/appledoc-documentation-comments/)

Comment: So basically, if I have appledoc, that is going to use that comment to write a documentation? nice :)

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, a comment is only delimited by /* */, so you are right, the exclamation point is not necessary to form a comment. However, in this case, the ! there is to say that that commment should be read by an auto-documentation tool, such as Doxygen or AutoDoc. The same goes for the @ symbols there. @property is saying that you are documenting a property called masterVolume and @abstract is describing what the property is for.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Qt comment style. It is treated as a block comment by [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl), [Headerdoc](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/headerdoc.html), and [Appledoc](http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp/). The author was familiar with Qt programming and chose that comment style. He could have chosen `/**` instead, just a matter of taste.