# How can I get Xcode to show my documentation comments during option-hover?

Tags: xcode, comments

I've read [What are documentation comments in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605535/what-are-documentation-comments-in-xcode) but I tried all these techniques and still can't get XCode 4.6 to show my comments during an option-hover (i.e. hold down alt, move mouse over method name, cursor changes to a ?, click). It says where it's declared, but nothing else. Am I doing something wrong or does XCode just not support doc comments?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode's option-click quick-help feature reads detailed information from installed documentation sets.

To get similar functionality, you would have to create your own documentation set and add it to Xcode under **Preferences > Downloads > Documentation**.

Comment: I found this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958413/xcode-show-documentation-for-my-custom-classes - and it looks like [appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) is a good tool for creating a doc set and getting it to reload when needed.