# Xcode 5 new documentation parsing comment on same line as property or method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, doxygen, xcode5

For property and method declarations I want to use XCode 5's new document parsing to get documentation for the comment at the end of the line, but nothing I have tried seems to have worked.

None of these work:

```
- (BOOL)open;   /**< @Returns NO if already open */
- (BOOL)open;   /*!< @Returns NO if already open */
- (BOOL)open;   //!< @Returns NO if already open
                //!<
- (BOOL)open;   ///< @Returns NO if already open
                ///<
```

But putting the documenation before the method does seem to work

```
/**
 @Returns NO if already open
 */
- (BOOL)open;
```

Is it possible in XCode 5 to document on the same line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605535/what-are-documentation-comments-in-xcode    was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that it is not possible with XCode 5.0.2. So this is the preferred syntax:

```
/// @Returns NO if already open
- (BOOL)open;
```